# HTML Set Carousel image src when it's active

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, bootstrap-4

I basically have two carousels setup in one page.

I want to be able to change the first carousel item active src from second carousel item src onclick.

What I did was

My second carousel item looks like this:

```
<div style="max-width: 20%; max-height: 20%;" class="col-sm-3">
<img style=" margin-left:100%;border-radius: 8px; height:100px;" src="{{column}}" onclick="setMainImage('{{image}}')" class="img-responsive" alt="test1">
```

My first carousel item that needs to be changed based on my second carousel on click item.

```
<div style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" class="item{% if loop.index == 1 %} active{% endif %}">
<center>  
<img style="margin:auto;height:400px;" src="{{item}}" id="main_image" class="img-responsive" alt="test1">

<script>
    function setMainImage(img) {            
        console.log(img)
        console.log($('#main_image').attr('src', img)); 
    }
</script>
```

When I do setMainImage that function is workign properly and console.log gives me correct image. I want to set that image to my first carousel .item active .img src attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are rendering multiple carousel items and marking down with the `active` class the one you want to be changed by the JS function.

If that's true, you have a problem rendering the different images inside the carusel items, you are assigning `main_image` id to all of them.

That way, when you invoke jquery `$('#main_image').attr` function it doesn't know what is the element it needs to change, as the id `main_image` is not unique.

You can either render only the `id='main_image'` when you are on the loop iteration you chose with something like what you do with the `active` class:

```
<center><img style="margin:auto;height:400px;" src="{{item}}"{% if loop.index == 1 %} id="main_image"{% endif %} class="img-responsive" alt="test1">
```

Or you can make your JQuery selector more specific selecting the id `main_image` that's under an `active` class:

```
$('.active #main_image').attr('src', img);
```

Comment: I tried; when I clicked on one image; it only worked. Multiple images doesn't seem to be working :( Here's my most portion of the code. Maybe you can replicate the issue?https://pastebin.com/R9sKyNeJ

Comment: Could you please share the rendered html code instead of the twig template? That way I'll probably be able to diagnose what is happening, with the twig template I don't know what are you sending to it from the controller :)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for replying. I've solved this issue with your help. I was just having other issues causing your code not to work, now it's working as expected. Thanks! Marking this as answer.